# Car is taking longer to start as it warms up? (Vid included)

Tags: starting, rpm, crank

2007 Lexus ES350 with 132k miles. I recently started using it for uber eats this past Friday and I'm in NYC.

The car starts up fine when cold. But I notice after a few stops and shutting the car off, and turning it back on since I'm getting the food, then delivering, it starts to get slower to crank. The dash dims as it takes longer to crank. Not sure if it's related to the engine temp.

The battery is brand new and was manufactured in December, and I installed it last month. Yes, the terminals were cleaned. I had the alternator, battery and starter tested at autozone and it all came back as good, although I couldn't replicate the problem there.

[Here](https://streamable.com/ewqqx3) is a video from yesterday I took. (Sorry at the last second the radio comes on, be aware headphone users). This was the longest it took to crank over yet. It went over when I let go of the start stop button.

This is my first car and I learned to hold the push the start until it cranks over, but as I was trying to find a solution online I read some just need a simple press. I started doing that and it seemed better, but today I did it and the car struggled again, and for the next minute the car was shaking at idle as I was parked. At one point the RPM needle dipped down for a second. I couldn't replicate for a video.

So what's going on? Something fuel related? I posted a thread 7 months ago on another forum how my fuel injectors looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiAjZ.jpg). I was told they are just damp and not really a leak. Not sure if that helps. I changed the spark plugs myself around the time as well. MAF sensor and intake were cleaned too. The hidden menu reports 13.3-13.7V.
The only current problem I have is a power steering leak and I'm sure it's unrelated. So any ideas of what to do to narrow this down? Thanks! For the meantime, I'm just going to leave my car parked and not deliver with it.

Edit: Nope.  I notice also that when I was turning on my headlights yesterday, the  rpm's fluctuated a bit, and I think when I turned on the AC.

Edit 2:
Hi. So I forgot my family member has a OBD2 scanner, and thankfully it can show some live data on my phone.

First it says my check engine is on, which it's not. The bulb isn't burnt out, cause I see it when the lights turn on. It triggered 2.5 days ago it says. Anyways, the code was P0300. I checked my long term and short term fuel numbers

At start for a cold engine, @ idle @ 33F/1C outside
Short Term Bank 1: -7.81%

Short Term Bank 2: -5.47%

Long Term Bank 1: 17.19%

Long Term Bank 2: 16.41%

Engine at operating temp @ idle @ 33F/1C outside

Short Term Bank 1: 1.56%

Short Term Bank 2: 1.56%

Long Term Bank 1: 10.94%

Long Term Bank 2: 12.50%

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks! I'm honestly a bit perplexed by the problem, although due to the current weather I can't really investigate, so I'm trying to see if anyone has an idea. Do you have some thoughts?

Comment: I'm wondering if the starter is having issues. Where, when the starter gets warm, it isn't working as well. Just because it spins outside of the car doesn't mean it isn't getting dead. I'm not saying "go run out and buy a new starter", but if you have the knowhow, you could pull it apart and see how the brushes and armature are looking. Just a thought.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Hi. Thanks for the response. Well the thing is I don't have a garage, I usually have to use my friend's which is a bit of a drive, so it takes me a while before we set up a day where we are both available, and the current weather sucks for this. BUT, I just added some info, check my second edit in the post! Perhaps getting closer to the issue? I actually was on Scotty Kilmer's live stream today and he also suspected the starter. I know a lot of people don't like him on many forums but I just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: You can't judge anything on a cold start when it comes to your trims. When its cold, it's in fuel enrichment mode and in open loop. Once it gets to a point, it will cut back fuel trims and go to closed loop, where it will run normally.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Makes sense! What about at operating temp? Or is that not really useful since I just turned the car on until it warmed up, and I didn't drive it.

Comment: From cold, it'll take a couple of minutes for it to go from open to closed loop. Once the engine is at operating temps, it will be in open loop for a few seconds until it realizes the engine is already warm, then will move to closed. Just thinking, whether in closed or open loop (and therefore also you trims) won't have much of an effect on whether it's starting or not.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Hi. Well how do the ones at engine temp look? Is this something that can cause the issue as well, or is it problem parallel to this one? I checked my coil resitances in cylinder 2,4,6 and fuel injector resistances, all were consistent (Can't currently access 1,3,5, much harder to get to on the street). But a tiny smidge of oil on each coil, as if you took a drop on your finger and smeared it. Hole looks dry for the spark plug, but the old spark plugs had some oil on the threads.